# Does CoreLocation already use QZSS or other GNSS in addition to GPS?

Tags: ios, swift, gps, core-location

According to Apple Documentation it looks like only GPS is used in core location as that is the only requirement in the property list. However, many websites claim that iPhones have support for GNSS and incorporate it into the core location? Does anyone know how to access the satellite signals raw to do our own calculations?

Does anyone have any information on this? If Core Location already incorporates QZSS then I do not have to worry, but if not then I would like to try incorporating it myself.

Is there any further specification?

Comment: "GPS" in this case is generic for "location hardware". Some devices such as iPod touch and some iPads do not have location hardware and so cannot deliver accurate location. Core location uses a range of data including satellite signals, cellular data and wifi networks to determine location.  If an external location receiver is connected via Bluetooth or CarPlay it will use that. There is no way to access the raw location data. The [tech specs](https://www.apple.com/au/iphone-13-pro/specs/) show which location receivers are fitted.

Comment: Thank you I appreciate the answer. I also assumed GPS was being used generically as well, but I wanted to be sure since it isn't clear in the documentation. 

So the answer here is that iPhone may or may not be using QZSS but there is no way to know how, and there is definitely no way to access the raw sensor data either.